# Select and format text in table cells based on Regex criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How do I loop through all the cells in a table, selecting text in each cell based on Regex criteria, and format those cells?

EDIT: I can set row attributes using `table.getRow(n).getCell(n)` but how do I format specific text in each cell?

I need to make the name appearing at the start of each cell **bold**:

[image]

Here's the [sample doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cEjSwdR4KFtBvVRSFG-V_eiVq1OGVKleMdMHeDVsKGQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thanks Rubén - will do in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- In your sample situation, you want to convert the value of `Monserrat Banks` of `Monserrat Banks: Fringilla dolor ultricies aliquam dolor.` to the bold type in a table on Google Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document and run the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const table = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getTables()[0];
  const rows = table.getNumRows();
  for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    const row = table.getRow(r);
    const cols = row.getNumCells();
    for (let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      const cell = row.getCell(c);
      const f = cell.findText(".*:");
      if (!f) continue;
      cell.editAsText().setBold(f.getStartOffset(), f.getEndOffsetInclusive() - 1, true);
    }
  }
}
```

- From your provided Document, in this sample, the 1st table is used. When you want to use another table, please modify the above script.

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided Google Document, the following result is obtained.

##### From:

[image]

##### To:

[image]

#### Rererences:

- [getTables()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#gettables)
- [setBold(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, bold)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setboldstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-bold)